# How to reset counter on zero on API controller

Tags: java

I have an API that on each call return me a random document from MongoDB collection.

This is code:

```
AtomicInteger countSummerCamps = new AtomicInteger();

@GetMapping("/getRandomSummerCamps")
public String getRandomSummerCamps(Model model) {

    countSummerCamps.incrementAndGet();

    if (getCountSummerCamps() <= adventureHolidaysService.countAdventureHolidays("summerCamps")) {
        model.addAttribute("randomSummerCamps", adventureHolidaysService.findRandomAdventureHolidays("summerCamps"));

        return "randomSummerCamps";

    } else {

        return "noMoreDoc";
    }
}
```

What is my problem and how I tried.

So in this situation the program will return me four elements in HTML. And after that the program will show me a `noMoreDoc` page. That works fine. But the problem is when I refresh the page. It’s still page `noMoreDoc` even if I go on the home page and hit the API again. It’s still the `noMoreDoc` page. I want to avoid that and after the user refreshes the page and get back on `/getRandomSummerCamps` show the user random documents again on every call.

I tried to set `counterSummerCamps.set(0)` inside `}else{`, but I got *"Unreachable statement"*.

Is there a way to fix this, so after the user got the `noMoreDoc` page and after the user get back on, to `/getRandomSummerCamps` show the user random documents again on each call?

Comment: You are trying to achieve pagination but the issue is HTTP is a stateless protocol and you are incrementing the variable in the backend, rather I suggest you move the logic to the frontend (i.e) send the number of the element trying to access and return the corresponding element, if it goes beyond then return "noMoreDoc" in that way even if the page refreshes it will be set to zero in the frontend.

Comment: How I can consume this in front? `adventureHolidaysService.countAdventureHolidays("summerCamps")) {` here I call method that count how many elements are in collection

Answer (score 0):

If you call `counterSummerCamps.set(0)` after the return statement of else, you will get unreachable code. Try to set it before the return statement.